# How to create a repeatString Function

Tags: javascript

so I am very new to js and I'm having a really hard time comprehending the language. Could anyone take 5 to look at this code and tell me why my function isn't working...?  The goal is to create a function that duplicates a string by the number inputted into the function.

```
function repeatString(string, num) {
return string*num
}
var output=repeatString("Hello!",2);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Why would that work? Guessing is not the way to go

Comment: the `*` operator, when used with a string and a number, results in NaN. Perhaps use String.concat (or string.repeat if you want to cheat)

Comment: function repeatString(s, num) {
 if(num > 1) {
  s += ' '+ repeatString(s, num-1);
 }
 return s;
}

Here is a recursive approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply call the `repeat` method:

```
function repeatString(string, num) {
    return string.repeat(num);
}
```

Comment: You were faster! And here's the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Comment: Be advised no versions of Internet Explorer support this, so a polyfill may be needed.